# connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.44.215] failed: Connection timed out

Tags: java, apache, maven

I’m trying to build a java web services app maven project on linux centos but get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.44.215] failed: Connection timed out.
```

I can resolve the url to an ip:

```
nslookup repo.maven.apache.org
Server:         69.252.80.80
Address:        69.252.80.80#53

Non-authoritative answer:
repo.maven.apache.org   canonical name = repo.apache.maven.org.
repo.apache.maven.org   canonical name = maven.map.fastly.net.
Name:   maven.map.fastly.net
Address: 23.235.40.215
```

And ping the server ok

```
-sh-4.1$ ping 69.252.80.80
PING 69.252.80.80 (69.252.80.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 69.252.80.80: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from 69.252.80.80: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=1.13 ms
```

But if I ping the url directly, no response

```
ping repo.maven.apache.org
PING maven.map.fastly.net (23.235.47.215) 56(84) bytes of data
```

I tried adding

```
    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Central</name>
                    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>             
                    <id>plugins</id>
                    <name>Plugins</name>
                    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/</url>
             </repository>
    </repositories>
```

to the pom.xml.  Same result.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Greg

Comment: Can you connect to the [server](https://repo.maven.apache.org/) using a web browser? Keep in mind that you need to use `https` in order to connect to port `443`, to duplicate what Maven is trying to do.